# Kubuntu rc.local script start just before window system

Tags: ubuntu, linux

I need to execute a custom bash script just before the window system is started during the boot process. I know Kubuntu uses Upstart to handle the boot process. According to this page `https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto`, there is no concept of runlevels in Upstart; everything is event driven with dependencies. How do I then configure my script to run at the moment that would be equivalent to runlevel 5 in System V, that is, just when the window system is loaded? Some variation of this?

```
update-rc.d myscript defaults
```

I need it to be executed as root, but I assume that's given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of attacking this via `upstart`, consider attacking it via `lightdm` itself. LightDM has hooks that get executed at different points during the desktop lifecycle. In particular the script specified as `display-setup-script` gets executed before the desktop starts up.

Alternatively, if you really want to do this via upstart, you could add a service that is configured to

> start on starting lightdm

This is assuming of course that you're using lightdm, which is the standard Display Manager. If you're using KDE you might be using kdm and I'm not familiar with what hooks it provides, but most Display Managers (e.g. `GDM`) provide similar hooks.

References: 
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM 
http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/

Comment: I am using lightdm, so this should work. I'll give it a shot! Thanks.

Comment: Be forewarned that `lightdm` executes `display-setup-hook` every time the desktop starts - e.g. after a logout.

Comment: Can you please let me know where I find the display-setup-hook? I am trying to google it and nothing is coming up and `locate display-setup-hook` doesn't return any file on my computer either.

Comment: Sorry typo - just fixed the answer above. The correct name for the hook is display-setup-script. It is not a file delivered on your system, it is a configuration parameter for lightdm that specifies a script (provided by you) to run at that point of the desktop lifecycle. See the first reference in my answer for details.